# div width 100% across

Tags: html, width

simple question

if I make a div with border all way round with some text in, the div box will only be as wide as the content.

how do I make it that the div always stretches 100% of the screen across, even if nothing inside it.

I understand min-width doesnt work with IE, is there a safe, stable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a `<div>` will always take up the 100% of width unless a style(css) alters it.
Keep in mind that a `<div>` is a `block` element.

If you set the display value of `<div>` to be `inline`, for example, it would only take up the width of its content.

Example:

```
.myDiv
{
   display: inline;
}

<div class="myDiv">I will take up width of my content only</div>
```

On the otherhand,

A `<span>` will only take up as much width as the context because its an `inline` element.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bBFKL/) is an example.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBFKL/)